# Calling setState on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

In a lot of my components I need to do something like this:

```
handleSubmit() {
  this.setState({loading: true})
  someAsyncFunc()
    .then(() => {
      return this.props.onSuccess()
    })
    .finally(() => this.setState({loading: false}))
}
```

The `onSuccess` function

- may or may not be a promise (if it is, `loading` should stay true until it is resolved)
- may or may not unmount the component (it may close the modal this component is in or even navigate to different page)

If the function unmounts the component, `this.setState({loading: false})` obviously triggers a warning `Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.`

My 2 questions:

1. Is there a simple way to avoid the issue ? I don't want to set some `_isMounted` variable in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and then check it when needed in most of my components, plus I may forget to do it next time writing something like this ...
2. Is it really a problem ? I know that, according to the warning, `it indicates a memory leak in my application`, but it is not a memory leak in this case, is it ? Maybe ignoring the warning would be ok ...

EDIT: The second question is a little bit more important for me than the first. If this really is a problem and I just can't call `setState` on unmounted component, I'd probably find some workaround myself. But I am curious if I can't just ignore it.

Live example of the problem:

```js
const someAsyncFunc = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   console.log("someAsyncFunc resolving");
    resolve("done");
  }, 2000);
});

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {loading: false};
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.handleSubmit(), 100);
  }
  
  handleSubmit() {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    someAsyncFunc()
      /*
      .then(() => {
        return this.props.onSuccess()
      })
      */
      .finally(() => this.setState({loading: false}))
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>{String(this.state.loading)}</div>;
  }
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
 constructor(props, ...rest) {
   super(props, ...rest);
    this.state = {
     children: props.children
    };
  }
 componentDidMount() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     console.log("removing");
     this.setState({children: []});
    }, 1500)
  }
 render() {
   return <div>{this.state.children}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Wrapper>
    <Example />
 </Wrapper>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Comment: In component modal closing and navigation,why you need loading false?Anyway the state associated with it going to destroy

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN As I wrote: the `onSuccess` function **may or may not unmount the component** - in some cases, the modal should stay open, without loading of course ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - setState() on unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903001/react-setstate-on-unmounted-component)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to keep track of "isMounted" yourself.
To simplify you control flow you could use `async/await`:

```
handleSubmit() {
  this.setState({loading: true})
  try {
    await someAsyncFunction()
    await this.props.onSuccess()
  } finally {
    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({loading: false})
    }
  }
}
```

This is actually mentioned in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html), which points to this solution: https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/982ab689a41097237f6e9860db7ca8d6

If your `someAsyncFunction` supports cancelation, you should do so in [componentWillUnmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount), as encouraged by [this article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html). But then - of course - check the return value and eventually not call `this.props.onSuccess`.

Comment: Upvoted because you are technically correct, but I am actually more interested if I can't just ignore the warning. I updated the question ...

Comment: Thanks. I think you should never tolerate a warning. A newer version of React might get stricter in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

```
class myClass extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this._getData();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  _getData() {
    axios.get('example.com').then(data => {
      if (this._isMounted) {
        this.setState({ data })
      }
    });
  }


  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `this._isMounted` to check if the component is actually mounted.

```
handleSubmit() {
  this.setState({loading: true})
  someAsyncFunc()
    .then(() => {
      return this.props.onSuccess()
    })
    .finally(() => {
      if (this && this._isMounted) { // check if component is still mounted
        this.setState({loading: false})
      }
    })
}
```

But be aware that this approach is considered to be an anitpattern. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: So `this` is already `undefined` at that stage? You could check that, too. I updated my answer.

Comment: No, check the last line of the article you linked in your answer: `Getting rid of isMounted() makes it one step easier for you to upgrade to ES6 classes, where using isMounted() is already prohibited`. It's just not in react anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
componentWillUnmount() {  
    // Assign this.setState to empty function to avoid console warning
    // when this.setState is called on an unmounted component
    this.setState = () => undefined;
}
```