# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to send the state to another component using a Link, but it always gave me this error

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

I would like to know what are the best solution to avoid this kind of conflict.

and thanks on advance

```
class Home extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        data: {},
        name: ""
    }
    this.createRoomHandler = this.createRoomHandler.bind(this)
}
 createRoomHandler() {

    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.eyeson.team/rooms",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": ""

        },
        "data": {
            "user[name]": this.state.name
        }
    }



    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

        this.setState({ data: response });
        console.log("ashraf", response)
    })


}
  createNamehandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value })

}
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.createRoomHandler()
}
render() {

    return (
        <div className="create-room-container">
            <input onChange={this.createNamehandler} />
            <Link to={{ pathname: "CreateStream", query: 
            this.state.data }} > <button onClick= 
            {this.createRoomHandler}>Create 
  Room</button></Link>
        </div>
    )
  }

}
```

export default Home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - setState() on unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903001/react-setstate-on-unmounted-component)

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillUnmount = () => {
  this.createRoomHandler()
}
```

Firstly you're creating an arrow function for no reason, they are normally for callbacks which don't have the correct `this` reference otherwise. Also you are using `.bind` in the constructor when there is no need as you've already used arrow functions elsewhere (use them instead).

You're calling `setState` as the component is unmounting which doesn't make sense. If you want to make a request when a component unmounts for some reason then call a method which doesn't try and set state on a component which no longer exists (setState is **async** so finishes after the component is supposed to be removed and so causes a mem leak) e.g. to a redux store instead.

You will need to cancel timers such as `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, cancel XHR requests (ideal) or else don't call setState when they complete if the component has unmounted. Also don't trap references from the component inside request callbacks or that will leak memory too.